# Referencing self variables outside of original class

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 100
        self.stats = {'STR': 0,
                     'DEF':0}

class create_character(object):
    def choose_class(self):
        inp = input("Please choose a class!: ").lower()
        s = ("Knight, Archer, or Mage")
        print(s)
        if inp == 'knight':
            self.stats['STR'] = 15
            self.stats['DEF'] = 15
            print(self.stats)
```

The problem I'm facing currently, is that when I reference self.stats under create_character, it tells me that specific class doesn't have a 'self.stats'.  If I try player.self.stats or player.stats, it tells me the same thing, that the class doesn't have those attributes.  How can I reference a dictionary or a variable from another class, and change its properties.  Also, when I print self.health, or self.stats, or self.name or whatever properties the player class hold, it gives me a bunch of unneeded information.  Is there a way to exclude the extra information?

Comment: That... doesn't make any sense. Why is `create_character` a class? Why did you expect it to have the same attributes as a completely unrelated class that just happened to be defined above it? Why would you expect the class `player` to have the attributes you define only on instances of that class? And what precisely do you mean by *"a bunch of unneeded information"*? I strongly recommend you find and follow a Python OOP tutorial to get to grips with the basics.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this will do the job that you are looking for:

```
class player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 100
        self.stats = {'STR': 0,
                     'DEF':0}

def choose_class():
    inp = input("Please choose a class (Knight, Archer, or Mage): ").lower()
    if inp == 'knight':
        # create the player object
        p = player()
        # changes the values for the attributes in the player object
        p.stats['STR'] = 15
        p.stats['DEF'] = 15
        print(p.stats)

# calls the function to choose the class
choose_class()
```

This is not really a good coding style though, so I would recommend following an OOP Python tutorial.